# Counting amount of '//' in a dataset (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a question related to a SQL Server query.
I want to count all '//' in a dataset. The dataset contains a code. Through counting the '//' i want to declare it as a Comment, IF EVERY SINGLE ROW contains at least one time the string '//'.

Actually I've count the amount of '//' in a dataset, but i don't know how should i continue.

```
select col1, col2, LEN(col3) - LEN(REPLACE(col3, '//', '' )) AS col3counter
from #tmp
```

Comment: Add some sample data, question is not very clear. What DBMS you are using , SQL is a query language

Comment: Do you also want the trailing `//`s after the first appearance. I mean, `// xyz //abc` will be counted for one or two?

Comment: @Ven Ok I'll go more detail. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 in T-SQL. The table which I want to change is a table with a list of actions. Every action has a program code in Javascript (but this is not important because the code is written in col3). Ive moved the code in a dataset to analyze it. In the dataset where the code is I want to check every single row. If in every single row there is a leading "//" i want to mark it. That would be the signal for me that the code in the dataset is completely outcommented.

Comment: @vahdet I only want the '//' where it is the first character (skip blanks) in a row. It doesnt matter what is written after the double-slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get twice the count.  So either divide by 2 or:

```
select col1, col2,
       ( LEN(col3) - LEN(REPLACE(col3, '//', 'x' )) ) AS col3counter
from #tmp
```

Comment: I recognized this problem also..sorry :-). If i make a space between the apostrophs in the length function this issue will be also solved..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for double-posting but I solved the issue on my own :-). Code is...

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4,
    LEN(col3) - LEN(REPLACE(col3, '//', ' ' )) AS col3commentcount,
    LEN(col3) - LEN(Replace(col3,(char(13)+char(10)),' '))+1 as  col3rowcount,
    LEN(col4) - LEN(REPLACE(col4, '//', ' ')) AS col4commentcount,
    LEN(col4) - LEN(REPLACE(col4,(char(13)+char(10)),' '))+1 as col4rowcount
from #tmp
where LEN(col3) - LEN(REPLACE(col3, '//', ' ' )) = 
  LEN(col3) - LEN(Replace(col3,(char(13)+char(10)),' '))+1 OR
  LEN(col4) - LEN(REPLACE(col4, '//', ' ')) =
  LEN(col4) - LEN(REPLACE(col4,(char(13)+char(10)),' '))+1
  and idcheck=0  
order by col1
```